# JavaScript - clearWatch() doesn't cancel watchPosition(), just defaults to error callback

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I'm working with JavaScript's [watchPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) and [clearWatch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/clearWatch), which mostly behave as needed - `watchPosition()` watches a user's location, `clearWatch()` stops that process. However, I find that if I call `clearWatch()` before `watchPosition()` has returned a value (while it is still trying to get a user's location from their device and has not yet returned `success` or `error`), `watchPosition()` continues to run until it returns its `error` callback with a timeout error. I don't want that to happen, though, I just want to kill the process entirely - is there any way that I can hook into that?

Here is my relevant code:

```
let userLocation,
    isWatching = false

const clearWatch = (userLocation) => {
    return window.navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(userLocation)
},
success = (position) => {
    const latitude = position.coords.latitude,
        longitude = position.coords.longitude,
        accuracy = position.coords.accuracy

    console.log(latitude, longitude, accuracy)
},
error = (err) => {
    isWatching = false
    return alert(`Error ${err.code}: ${err.message}`)
},
watch = () => {
    userLocation = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, {
        "maximumAge": 0,
        "timeout": 15000,
        "enableHighAccuracy": true
    })
}

watchPositionButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (isWatching) {
        isWatching = false
        clearWatch(userLocation)
    } else {
        isWatching = true
        watch()
    }
})
```

If I click `watchPositionButton`, it usually takes about 5 seconds to get the `success` callback, and if I then click the button again, it tears everything down, perfect. However, if the second cancelling click occurs in the window of time before the function returns `success`, after 15 seconds the error condition is returned and I get a timeout alert. Well why is that? And what can I do about it? Ideally, calling `clearWatch()` would just kill the entire process, but instead it seems to default to the `error` callback.

Comment: @RolandStarke sorry that was just a typo - I renamed a variable to make the code read a little easier, shot myself in the foot. I've fixed it.

Comment: ok :) ... one thing i noted while testing is that the error function can get called multiple times.... so after 5 timeouts there can still come an success.

Comment: I can't realy reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/b2er4zs4/2/

Comment: @RolandStarke in the fiddle, change the timeout from 1500 to 15000 - it's returning that too fast, it takes longer than 1500 milliseconds to get the location. Click the button, then immediately click it again, then wait 15 seconds.

Comment: then idk.... i am on desktop and can't click that fast (like the coordinates show instantly)... how about ignoring all errors if `isWatching` is false? ... (repetitive clicking the button could then still result in old errors to be shown)

Comment: @RolandStarke Hah, it takes my machine a few seconds to return it... ultimately, the app is intended for mobile, which usually takes a little time.  Ok, that's a good suggestion - I'll try that out. I wish I could kill the process, but that may not be possible...